# Typing in jMeter

Tags: filter, jmeter, response, autosuggest, typing

Is there any option how to simulate keyboard typing in jMeter? Ive got filter field with autosuggestions and I want to test response time of it. I want to start typing something like "W","Wa","Wash","Washi" etc. but for values loaded from CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter operates on HTTP protocol level, not browser level. Therefore you shouldn't try to emulate typing. What you can do is to capture (record) HTTP request triggered by such change, and later run this as part of your JMeter test.

My advice is - try not to overcomplicate it. JMeter (or perf testing in general)  & async calls can be tricky!